# Using column values from 1 df to another pandas

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns

```
[IN] df
[OUT]:
customer_id      Order_date   Status 
1                2015-01-16      R
1                2015-01-19      G
2                2014-12-21      R
2                2015-01-10      G
1                2015-01-10      B
3                2018-01-18      Y
3                2017-03-04      Y
4                2019-11-05      B
4                2010-01-01      G
3                2019-02-03      U
3                2020-01-01      R
3                2018-01-01      R
```

Code to extract Customer_IDs where count of order_trasactions is at least 3:

```
[IN]
df22=(df.groupby('customer_id')['order_date'].nunique().loc[lambda 
x:x>=3].reset_index()).rename(columns={'order_date':'Count_Order_Date'})
[OUT]      
         Customer_id     Count_Order_Dates
             1                  3
             3                  5
```

**Output I want:**
    I want to use the IDs that I got using this above code in the original dataframe df so I need the output as follows:

```
  [OUT]
  customer_id      Order_date   Status 
1                2015-01-16      R
1                2015-01-19      G
1                2015-01-10      B
3                2018-01-18      Y
3                2017-03-04      Y
3                2019-02-03      U
3                2020-01-01      R
3                2018-01-01      R
```

So in the output only ID 1 and 3 are reflected(ones where there were at least 3 or more unique order dates).

What i have tried so far (which has failed):

```
 df[df['customer_id'].isin(df22['customer_id'])]


 Reason it has failed I feel is because when I do df['customer_id'].nunique() and  
 df22['customer_id'].nunique(), values are different in both the cases.
```

Comment: use my solution from the previous question without the second groupby: `df[df.groupby('customer_id')['Order_date'].transform('nunique').ge(3)]`

Comment: TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int
 Error message

Comment: okay, how about the `filter` one: `df.groupby('customer_id').filter(lambda x: x['Order_date'].nunique()>=3)` <- this should work

Comment: Your solution should work fine , did you assign it back df= df[df['customer_id'].isin(df22['customer_id'])]

Comment: @YOandBEN_W No i dont think i assigned it back. let me check

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor if you assign it back, the df should be changed :-)

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple error. I had forgotten to reassign df value to df[df['customer_id'].isin(df22['customer_id'])]

So doing

```
 df =  df[df['customer_id'].isin(df22['customer_id'])]
```

solved my problem.

Thanks @YOandBEN_W for pointing it out.

Comment: I am allowed to accept by tomorrow. Will accept by that time :)